# Rails how to see changes on associated has_many models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Boat` and a `Price` model. A **Boat** `has_many :prices`. I need to track changes on the `prices` association of a `boat`:

- either when all prices of the boat are deleted
- or when a boat previously had no prices and now has some

Here is the code I came up with:

```
class Boat < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :prices, dependent: :destroy

  def priceable_changed?
    prices_deleted || prices_created
  end

  def prices_created
    prices.any? && prices.map {|p| p.saved_changes? }.all?
  end

  def prices_deleted
    prices.empty? && prices.select { |p| p.destroyed? }.any?
  end
end
```

However it seems it works in some case but won't in some other cases

```
    # Create a boat with no prices
    > boat = FactoryBot.create(:boat)
    > boat.priceable_changed? => FALSE      # OK

    # Add a previously created price to a boat
    > price = FactoryBot.create(:price, boat: boat)
    > boat.priceable_changed? => FALSE      # NOT OK

    # Create a price to the boat
    > boat.prices.create
    > boat.priceable_changed? => TRUE       # OK

    # Create a boat with prices
    > boat = FactoryBot.create(:boat, :with_3_prices)
    > boat.priceable_changed? => FALSE      # OK

    # Delete one price
    > boat.prices.last.destroy
    > boat.priceable_changed? => FALSE      # OK

    # Delete all prices at once
    > boat.prices.destroy_all
    > boat.priceable_changed? => FALSE      # NOT OK

    # Delete all prices one by one
    > boat.prices.map(&:destroy)
    > boat.priceable_changed? => TRUE      # OK
```

Is there a reliable way to do this? I feel like I'm doing it all wrong...
I'm using `Rails 5.2`.

Comment: The _unwanted_ behaviour on `destroy_all` is most likely caused by the [implementation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) of `destroy_all` that calls `reset` after each `destroy`. I see no workaround this...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help you but there is a gem `audited`. Check it out : https://rubygems.org/gems/audited.
It logs all changes to your models and it works with your Rails version !

Comment: Thanks, however I would prefer not using a gem for this _simple_ change tracking. I feel using a gem like [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/) or [papertrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) is an overkill...

And I don't want to track all the changes, just have some state change trigger an action